# Select MIN and MAX dates between two columns from different tables

Tags: sql

I have expenseDate (table A) and invoicedate (table B). There is no relation between those tables.

I need to get MIN and MAX dates between expenseDate and invoiceDate.

Since I'm not familiar with backend, could someone help? Thanks.

Comment: What database is it? That might make a difference. What are the data volumes? And do you mean the minimum and maximum of either expense date or invoice date?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT MIN(mydate) mindate, MAX(mydate) maxdate
FROM(
SELECT expenseDate AS mydate
FROM tableA
UNION ALL
SELECT invoicedate AS mydate
FROM tableB
) AS table
```

Comment: Take your time to test it, and make sure it is that you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

```
select min(datedata), max(datedata) from (
    select expensedate datedata from table A
    union all
    select invoicedate datedata from table B )
```

If this is what you want...

HTH

Comment: table must have its own alias

Comment: @Jeaffrey i would suggest using index on your date columns. Also for the indexes to work, it's better to have two queries, one for MIN and one for MAX.

Comment: @Jeaffrey Gilbert: it depends on the RDBMS sql implementation: sometimes you don't need a table alias.

Answer (score 0):

Initial thought is select MIN(expenseDate) and MIN(invoiceDate), and then return the lowest of those. Similarly with the highest.